# Real world application of slanted conics (parabolae especially)

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, quadratics

I am writing a report on slanted conics of the form 
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2= \dfrac{d}{\sqrt h}$$

Where $(h, k)$ is the focus, and $d$ is the directrix.

Are there any real world applications for *slanted* conics (parabolae)? I know many real world applications for regular parabolae, but slanted is different.

Comment: No, that's not the equation of a slanted conic, it's the equation of a circle with centre $(h,k)$ and radius $d^{1/2}/h^{1/4}$.

Comment: Then what do you think the standard equation for a slanted conic is?

Comment: slanted conics have a mixed term of the form $Kxy$.