# What's the standard form of the equation of a line of a slanted parabola?

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, conic-sections

I have been trying to figure out the general form of a slanted parabola, but what I've gotten doesn't look like it would be accurate:$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=\dfrac{d}{\sqrt{h}}$$Where $(h,k)$ is the focus, and $d$ is the directrix. Apparently, [slanted conics have a mixed term of the form $Kxy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058740/real-world-application-of-slanted-conics-parabolae-especially#comment2154982_1058740), but I cannot get that to apply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real world application of slanted conics (parabolae especially)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058740/real-world-application-of-slanted-conics-parabolae-especially)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, that question was one I asked about the real world applications of them, not the general form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to rotate the graph of a function?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17246/is-there-a-way-to-rotate-the-graph-of-a-function)

Comment: @ToClickorNottoClick I agree with you that your two questions are different, but I think the answer to the other question I linked to is also the answer to _this_ question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045286/find-tilted-parabola-equation-given-vertex-and-angle/1078334#1078334

See my answer here...  Pretty similar question.  To get the $xy$ term you just have to multiply everything out.

Answer (score 0):

I may have an answer, "Slanted parabolas are also parabolas". Sometime ago, I was trying to find a vector equation for parabola,

$$\vec{r} = \vec{a} + \lambda\vec{b} + \lambda^2\vec{c}$$
you might notice that, if $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ are not perpendicular, then you will get a slanted parabola.

e.g. let $\vec{a} = \vec{0}$, and $\vec{b}=\widehat{i}$ and $\vec{c}=c\widehat{i}+\widehat{j}$

For past few days, I've been playing with them, and I proved that, slanted parabolas are also parabolas which are rotated, and stretched by some amount. and I've proved that, for any vector $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{c}$ the above vector equation will always yield a parabola. and if you want some standard equation for slanted parabola, I can give you this,

$$x(\lambda) = \lambda + c\lambda^2$$
$$y(\lambda) = \lambda^2$$
draw the x-y graph for any fixed value of "c", you'll get a slanted parabola (which I proved is a parabola, you can try that yourself, just rotate the vector b and c such that c points upwards), you can scale the slanted parabolas to get all the possible slanted parabolas.

If you want a python matplotlib program which animates this, comment, I'll post it on github. And if you want the proof, I was talking about, I haven't written it in proper mathematical terms, but I can try to post that as well if you want.